# vertical DrawerLayout or SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android, android-widget, drawerlayout

The latest [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) introduced the [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) to implement the common UX pattern where you slide right or left to show a navigation menu.

What I'd love to have is a **vertical [DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html)** with the same API, that can be pulled down/up from the top/bottom of my layout.

Since 4.2 the old [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html) has been deprecated and I haven't heard about some new Widget that implements the same functionality.

Can the `DrawerLayout` be extended somehow to implement the vertical swipe UX pattern?
Does google provide some different widget to implement it?

[Google Music](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.music&hl=it) for instance has something very similar to what I'm looking to implement to pull up the player.

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

We have recently implemented this in the Umano App and open sourced: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Enjoy.

Comment: thanks, looks like what i was looking for. I ll give it try and then place the boundy.

Comment: Great work. That's exactly what i was looking for, you made the life easier for lots of people out there. I wonder why google kept this for itself.
PS: you made my day with the memes in the demo :)

Comment: Any chance of adding maven support ?

Comment: Hey Marco, it's not a library, to use the view, just copy it to your project.

Comment: Hey @tokudu, how can I add it to my IntelliJ project?

Comment: You couldnt have found a better way to promote your app; I was looking for a tech solution and now Im downloading a new app :D

Comment: How to use it a child of DrawerLayout?? Whenever i am making it child of DrawerLayout it not moving up on dragging remain stick to the bottom. An ideas??

Answer (score 12):

The Android support library now has the bottom sheets behavior to do that.

Check out this link for more info https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html

Comment: Thank you so much for this hint, I have been searching for a better solution than umanos Sliding Panel.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial for adding the bottom sheet per google specs.

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Comment: The link in the answer is obsolete, but this links to the class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, it makes more sense to use the `BottomSheetBehavior` that you can find more information on how setting it up on https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031

Basically, you need to set your main content, and your sliding content. The `BottomSheetBehavior` would only work for panels that you slide from the bottom to the top.

It has a quite simple set up and the `BottomSheetBehavior` could even work out of the box. Only by writing a `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout` layout, with another View inside (with even `wrap_content` as a value in the `layout_height` parameter), for instance a `LinearLayout` like this one:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <!-- Your content goes here -->

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my case, I inflate this layout in a `Fragment` and add it to the `Activity` where you want to enable the `SlidingSheetBehavior`.