# sliding layout like google maps v7

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

Im trying to get the same result as new google maps, when you "tap" on any "marker" you get a little layout in bottom of the screen, all the info about the srteet view and other details shown there, when you hold and move your finger to top of the screen the layout moves and c over all screen or half of the screen. i was thinking use slidingDrawer but seems google depreceate this method on api 17. so how i can achieve this?
Im attaching the image of example:
[image]

Comment: did you found a solution since ?

Comment: Nope, i couldng found a solution like this yet

Comment: i found a hint new feature un gmaps setpadding  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYvt0gpeFW4

Comment: yeah seems close what i want, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now from with Android Support Library 23.2 we can use [Design Support Library: Bottom Sheets](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

[image]

Comment: Google Maps under Lollipop was built using SDK 22 at that time we didn't had Bottom Sheets and/or support library API level 23.x. **exposed as public APIs** . I want to know how did they do it? :) As I am compiling using SDK level 22 and I can't use 23. Any other alternative other than 'SlidingUpPanel' lib

Answer (score 4):

you could look into using this [SlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) which appears to be exactly what you are looking for

Comment: seems what i want, however i need the "layout" can stop in the half of  the screen

Comment: If you call `setAnchorPoint(0.5f)` on the SlidingUpPanel view you can have the layout stop halfway up the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Something that might be worth looking into is the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551582/alternative-way-for-implementing-a-slidingdrawer-that-has-now-been-deprecated-si).

More specifically the answer that links [here](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-slidingdrawer-top-down-style/).

Basically the idea is that They realized that the sliding drawer left some things to be desired and they created a custom component with similar functionality. This will give you more freedom and a way around using deprecated classes. Let me know in comments if there's anything else that would be helpful to know.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi! I hope you can help me with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101513/view-which-can-be-pulled-up-with-a-floating-action-button-like-google-maps-app) a similar kind of question but using SDK level 22.