# How is the Google Maps layout animated?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation

I am trying to understand what animation is used in the Google Maps application.

The part I am trying to understand is when you click on the textbox in the toolbar. The layout animates to present a completely new screen with a few items sliding in from the bottom.

How is this done?  Is it a bottom sheet becoming visible? Is it a new activity with shared element transitions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sliding layout like google maps v7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236736/sliding-layout-like-google-maps-v7)

Comment: @cricket_007 Not a dup. That effect can be done fairly easily using a bottom sheet or a sliding up panel. :)

Comment: It used to be a sliding up panel pre lollipop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called activity transitions. Where you choose which layouts should been moved to a second activity. See also the official documentation about animations: http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions

Another good point to start it the video talk from the Google Developers: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM

Basically you need to modify the style like here:

```
<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
  <!-- enable window content transitions -->
  <item name="android:android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>

  <!-- specify enter and exit transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
  <item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>

  <!-- specify shared element transitions -->
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
  <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
</style>
```

You also need to specify a special attribute called `android:transitionName` to say the system that you want to move that from one activity to a second one.

Comment: AFAIK, activity transitions are a Lollipop feature. Are they available in appcompat? :)

Comment: No that is not possible since that animations run are on a different thread then the normal UI, however in this special case it might work too when you just replace fragments, with an animation.

Comment: Okay, in the Maps app, the same animation is done pre-Lollipop. Is it possible to apply animations to layouts in `onCreate( )` so that some elements slide in from bottom?

Comment: If this works in pre lollipop then they use probably just normal animations with fragments. In that case I would guess that they show a fragment where all elements are hidden by default after the fill animation of the background the elements are faided in.

Comment: I think OP is asking about this  https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel... Not transitions between Activities

Answer (score 1):

This is a single activity that has 2 modes: map mode and input+list mode. 
You can have a FrameLayout and within have the map root view (visible) and the input root view (gone). When you want to open the list, you make it visible and use ViewAnimation to animate it going up. 
A better approach is to break these 2 main views into 2 fragments, and animate the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

**The example that you are talking about is basically Google Places AutoComplete Api.**

Please follow the link for the same :

**https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete**