# View which can be pulled up with a floating action button like google maps app

Tags: android, material-design, android-custom-view, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I am trying to make something seen in Google Maps App when one clicks on a POI on the map a view comes up having a floating action button anchored to it.

In my scenario it is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug0Cf.png)  but there is already a FAB which is already visible and when an action is triggered a small view is visible with an anchored FAB showing some details and when it is pulled up it covers the screen just like an activity (something visible in the aforementioned google maps app).

I am compiling the app with SDK level 22 and 23 is out of scope so I can't use bottom sheets.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Bottom sheets is part of the support library and should work all the way to Gingerbread, you don't need SDK level 23 to use it, also there's no difference in using 22 or 23, as long as u code it properly it will work all the way to whatever is your minSdkVersion. So yeah, use bottom sheets

Comment: @Budius Thanks for the reply! So, in-order to use Bottom sheets in my project I would need to change dependency of my support lib to xxxx: **23.X** while I am still compiling with SDK level 22? Isn't that [not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32942918/1184579)? More in answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32939463/design-support-library-which-version-to-use-with-sdk-v21)

Comment: I apologize as it seems I was wrong on parts of my comment. But the idea of it still holds true. There's no good reason to not simply change the compileSdkVersion and use BottomSheets. As doing so will enable you to use the latest support library features and your app will compile and run just as before.

Comment: @Budius no probs mate. Infact I'd be more than willing to use level 23 but I just can't go forward with it. I think I'll go ahead with a 3rd party lib. I'd also like to point out that changing SDK levels for more features might seem pretty simple but starting from SDK level 23 and above if an app is compiled against 23 every extra feature(s) used would require user permissions to be asked first (also in google's SOP for android apps) whereas in case of SDK level 22 permission are given by default. So, most of the apps still using 22 remain crash free at first launch without denying any permis.

Comment: I can't think a reason you "can't" go with it. But if you're really decided on it, my suggestion is to use a decompiler on the support lib and then re-compile just the bottom with  SDK-22. Then you'll be sure to have a nicely build view that plays nicely with the CoordinatorLayout and FAB